# Who are the violent people seen in news about Hong Kong protests?

Tags: hong-kong

The news about the protests in Hong Kong are very mixed, and range from information about [very peaceful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiMZA1OUzUc) to [clearly violent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BztiwW-2pTE) events. Has there been any attempt to find out who those violent people are?

Are they protesting in order to get the [five demands](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/aug/13/what-do-the-hong-kong-protesters-want) met? That seems very strange; devastating MTR stations definitely isn't going to get them closer to that goal.

Are they [provocateurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_provocateur)? If so, have they been sent from mainland China or have they been recruited from among Hongkongers? Or are they regular Hong Kong citizens, who simply use the protests as an opportunity to channel their frustration into meaningless vandalism?

Beijing supporters and Hong Kong protesters obviously have different opinions on this matter, but I'm looking for a fact-based answer, to the extent possible.

Comment: Retracting, but this question needs some revision.  I would ask which group is precipitating the violence, the Chi-coms, the democracy protesters, or some other group.  You conflate protester with violence several times.

Comment: @KDog You can ask this question, that's an interesting topic too, but something different from what I asked here. My question is actually very simple. As we see in the video, there are some people who demolish MTR stations. Who are these people and why do they do such things?

Comment: Those videos may not be propaganda but it's impossible for us to differentiate between protesters and false flag operatives in those videos. A better question would be if there is any evidence of "provocateurs" having "been sent from mainland China". To make any statement on specific events in your videos will be very hard if not impossible (well, without access to local surveillance systems).

Comment: "Clearly violent events"? Fires that damage no property? Breaking glass well away from any people? I'm not sure that would qualify as a celebratory riot for the winning national high school robotics competition team's hometown.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet English is not my native language, so I looked up 'violent' in a dictionary, just to make sure: 'using or involving physical force intended to hurt, damage, or kill someone or something'. They clearly used physical force with the intention to damage the gates and barriers at the MTR station, so I can't see why you believe my description is incorrect.

Comment: @michau - "gates and barriers" and the dollar amount of damage or disruption caused by that damage is completely trivial, especially compared to actual protests that would be considered "violent." There are degrees of violence, and when the actual violent would could both be described as "violent" and "trivial," we just leave off the "violent" part, since it is trivial. Context matters. By using language that is used to describe much, much more serious activities, they try to conflate the level of damage or violence for those learning about it second hand.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I have lived in several countries in Europe and Asia, and in none of those places is such behaviour considered trivial. I have witnessed or taken part in protests in several countries, including Ukraine in 2004, and none of the protesters I've seen were as violent as the guys in the video. I don't know where you're from, perhaps in your country damaging public property is so common so as to be trivial and not even worth mentioning; that would explain our disagreement.

Comment: @michau - breaking windows with no one close is as violent as you've seen? Burning cardboard boxes away from buildings or other objects is as violent as you've seen? Either you are not as worldly as you claim, or you are engaging in hyperbole.  By your definition, if I'm sitting at my desk and a power glitch causes me to lose a spreadsheet I was working on, and I say "Darn" and snap a pencil I was holding, then I'm "clearly violent."   It's not completely peaceful, but it's vandalism, and controlled, at that. Actual violent protest - https://youtu.be/PCXs2l7l2zo?t=181.

Comment: Here's sports fans, after their team wins or loses, that are far more violent in their vandalism than anything you posted - https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2010677-15-crazy-riot-celebration-videos#slide0

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I can't see people damaging public property in these videos, at least in the ones I've seen (I'm not going to watch all 15). Oh, there is "serious damage" mentioned in relation to the riots in Pittsburgh. There is even a link to an [article](http://thetartan.org/2009/2/9/forum/riots) discussing the riots. And guess what, the article describes them as violent.

Comment: @michau - By your definition, there isn't anything that can't be described as "violent." If I snap a pencil, then I am using "physical force intended to damage something." As I said before, the violence you are referencing is trivial, and minor. "I can't see people damaging property" - the second one on the link with several is filled with fans destroying private property, especially vehicles.  The first one takes you to the part where the protestors are fighting each other. I think we're done here, as you are clearly here to troll a propaganda message, as previously accused. Have a nice day.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Is the author of the Pittsburgh riots article also a propaganda troll? If not, why is it OK to say the Pittsburgh rioters engaged in "violent and destructive behavior", while it's not OK to say the same about the people at the MTR station in the video?

Comment: @michau - Not sure where I ever said damage and vandalism could not be violent. I merely pointed out that the example you posted was very, very mild and intentionally staged to avoid widespread damage and human injury.  So when you claim it is "clearly violent," that false equivalence and more than a little hyperbole.  This is why I think you are trolling. The article linked about Pittsburgh is talking about a sports "celebration" in a city 1/25 the size of Hong Kong that was more violent than your example, so I'm not sure how confirming what I said serves as a rebuttal in your eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smashing of glass/windows which you describe as "violent" is par for the course for the Hong Kong protests, and probably for quite a few (politically charged) riots in Europe as well.

The glass-smashing scenes at the train stations have not received much commentary, but similar actions at government buildings [have](https://qz.com/1656991/why-hong-kong-protesters-destroyed-the-citys-legislature/):

> They destroyed the glass facade of the building. They tore up the Basic Law, Hong Kong’s mini constitution that sets it apart from mainland China’s legal system. They spray-painted over the city’s insignia, a bauhinia flower, but only the part that read “People’s Republic of China.” They put up the British colonial flag. They defaced the portraits of several former presidents of the legislature. And they scrawled a message for Carrie Lam, the city’s top official, on a pillar: “It was you who told me peaceful marches do not work.”
>
> [...]
>
> To critics, the occupation and destruction of the Legislative Council building was a violent turn in events that go against the ethos of peaceful demonstration and civil disobedience. The Hong Kong government has roundly condemned protesters’ “extreme use of violence” while Beijing has decried their “atrocities.”
>
> To others, the move is a cry for help from a marginalized and disenfranchised group of youths who have been forced to take extreme measures by an unrepresentative and unresponsive government, and for whom Hong Kong increasingly feels like a place where every opportunity is out of grasp. In storming the city’s heart of political power as politically powerless citizens, and targeting objects that to them represent the system’s inequities, the protesters delivered a scathing critique of the political establishment—albeit potentially at extremely high personal cost.
>
> [...]
>
> Some have observed that to a certain extent, the government’s handling of the mass protests of recent weeks has, whether intentionally or not, sent a message to demonstrators that merely peaceful rallies are not enough to sway official policy.
>
> Even after more than a million took to the streets on June 9 to demand the withdrawal of the extradition bill, the government doubled down on its position and insisted on pressing ahead with the legislation. It was not until three days after tens of thousands occupied major roads on June 12, leading to violent clashes between protesters and police, that Lam agreed to suspend the bill indefinitely. Addressing the press on June 15, Lam seemed to imply that it was only the violent confrontations earlier in the week that made her realize the urgency of the situation.And it was not until another several days later that Lam finally personally apologized—even though many found it to be insincere.

For comparison ["Macron denounces "extreme violence" after 'yellow vests' break into ministry courtyard"](https://www.euronews.com/2019/01/05/yellow-vest-protesters-play-out-act-8-in-paris). In such news the breaking of windows is barely worth a line, [e.g.](https://www.france24.com/en/20181201-french-police-deployed-amid-new-round-protests-over-taxes)

> Protesters also smashed the windows of shops including branches of Chanel, Dior and Apple.

See also WaPo's ["Five myths about riots"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/five-myths-about-riots/2015/05/01/e4469e52-ef72-11e4-8abc-d6aa3bad79dd_story.html). #1 myth is...

> Riots are caused by outside agitators and activists
>
> New York blamed “outside agitators” for violence in 1964. Ferguson did the same in 2014. Now Baltimore Mayor Stephanie Rawlings-Blake is blaming non-locals for the riots, and the police department insists that “outside agitators continue to be the instigators behind acts of violence and destruction.” Riots, however, are almost always homegrown. In Ferguson, only 21 percent of those arrested in August were from outside Missouri, and 76 percent were from Ferguson or surrounding towns. And of the 31 adults arrested in Baltimore as of last Sunday, only three were not Maryland residents.
>
> The main participants in riots, [my research](https://www.american.edu/sis/faculty/cschnei.cfm) shows, are usually young people from disadvantaged neighborhoods that have been virtually occupied by police; they usually feel powerless in the face of police brutality. When riots erupt, the balance of power momentarily inverts, and youths normally cowed by police experience a heady sense of efficacy and freedom.
>
> Activists, in contrast, rarely participate in riots. More confident in their ability to effect social change, experienced activists tend to channel community anger into nonviolent forms of collective action. Their presence actually makes riots less likely.